# Is there a way to reduce the size of requests when using <audio> with preload set to metadata

Tags: html, httprequest, metadata, html5-audio

I have an audio element on my page, set up like this:

```
<audio id="audio" controls preload="metadata">
    <source src="/audio/episode.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <source src="/audio/episode.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    [Not supported message]
</audio>
```

I was happy with `preload` being set to "metadata", because being able to see the length of the file is handy, and it's nice to be able to skip ahead without having to click the play button first.

But then I noticed that in Firefox and IE, this 'metadata' was loading between 20KB and 50KB. Chrome was worse, loading over 1MB. Seems like a lot of wasted bandwidth for a timestamp.

I know that `preload` is treated by browsers as [more what you'd call 'guidelines' than actual rules](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/media-elements.html#attr-media-preload). I've also found this [more in-depth article about the issue](https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/08/audio-the-preload-attribute/).

Are there any methods to reduce the size of these requests?

**What I've Tried/Considered**

I did try quickly cutting most of the metadata out of a file in a text-editor as a test. This made the requests in Firefox and IE *larger*, but it leaves me optimistic that there's some way to affect it positively.

I've also considered including the length on the page and setting it using javascript, but those settings appear to be read-only.

Finally, I've been thinking that as a last resort I could generate an empty audio file that is the exact same length, compress it down to as small a file as is possible, and then when the user interacts with it, swap it out for the real one*. At this point I realized I should probably get some help...

***EDIT:** I ended up trying this out! It's not going to work for my site, but at the very least its interesting. I included it as an answer below.

Comment: Take a look at [Media Source Extension](https://devdocs.io/dom/media_source_extensions_api).

Comment: @K3N: Can I use this just to load the length of the source file and then let the browser take over from there when the user hits play? Or does using Media Source Extensions mean I have to handle everything? The learning curve's hurting my brain a bit but hopefully I can get past that soon. Thanks by the way, this looks like exactly what I need!

Comment: Yes, MSE is "low-level" in the sense you'll have to handle most aspects of streaming/buffering/managing in your code. The file size should provided from the response as usual (unless it's an actual stream of course). Check out [this blog](https://www.wirewax.com/blog/post/building-a-media-source-html5-player/) for a example player based on MSE.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is hacky, but it does have a measurable effect. By loading the page initially with a silent doppelganger, and then switching it out for the real file when audio starts playing, I managed to save quite a bit on the initial page load.

Here are my average results with a 10 minute 20 second long mp3. Before and after:

IE: 16KB — Firefox: 43KB — Chrome: **1.4MB**

IE: 15KB — Firefox: 08KB — Chrome: 34KB

On Chrome the saving are 1.36MB, [more data than the full text of Crime and Punishment](http://idlewords.com/talks/website_obesity.htm). Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<audio id="audio" controls preload="metadata">
    <source src="/silence.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

**Javascript**

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
var time, volume, muted;

audio.addEventListener("playing", loadAudio, false);

function loadAudio(e) {
    time = audio.currentTime;
    volume = audio.volume;
    muted = audio.muted;
    audio.innerHTML = "<source src=\"/episode.mp3\" type=\"audio/mpeg\">";
    audio.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    audio.load();
    audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", playAudio, false);

    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
}        

function playAudio(e) {
    audio.currentTime = time;
    audio.volume = volume;
    audio.muted = muted;
    audio.play();

    e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
}
```

This was just written as a test; it can be improved quite a bit.

---

There are enough drawbacks to this method that I don't think I'll be using it. These include:

- You have to generate a silent copy of every single audio file you'd like to load this way.
- The users that actually play the audio will be requesting both files.
- It takes longer for the audio to start playing.
- The controls clearly switch to 0:00 and back again, especially when using high latency internet like mine.

That said, hopefully this method works for somebody out there! At the very least it was fun to play around with.